# Ajax return Json in Array, convert to string

Tags: php, json, ajax

Hello I have code Ajax to return value from databse:

```
function showResult(str) {
    action = 'http://localhost/mateusz/mateusz/public/villages/query/';
  if (str.length==0) {
    document.getElementById("resultSearch").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("resultSearch").classList.remove("border-search-city");
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("resultSearch").innerHTML=this.responseText;
      document.getElementById("resultSearch").classList.add("border-search-city");
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET",action + str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And code php to connect with databse:

```
public function query($name) {
    $villages = Village::select('id','name', 'province_id')->where('name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%')->get();

    for ($i=0; $i<=count($villages); $i++) {
      $returnQuery = $villages;
    }

    if ($returnQuery != '' || $returnQuery != null) {
      return '<a href="">'.$returnQuery.'</a>';
    } else {
      return "Nic nie mam";
    }
}
```

This is code form to search value:

```
  {!! Form::text('string', NULL, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'podaj frazę', 'onkeyup' => 'showResult(this.value)']) !!}
  <div id="resultSearch"></div>
```

Code php return me value in Json, look like this:

> [{"id":261,"name":"Dobre","province_id":2},{"id":1128,"name":"Dobre","province_id":7},{"id":1992,"name":"Dobre
>   Miasto","province_id":14}]

[image]
I need return value in `a href`, and every record from the new line.
Method `pluck()` and `toArray()` not work.

Edit:
I used `json_decode()`:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=count($villages); $i++) {
  $returnQuery = $villages;
}

if (!empty($returnQuery)) {
  $someArray = json_decode($returnQuery, true);
  print_r($someArray);
  echo $someArray[0]["name"];
}
```

But when I search name "Dobre" return only one record, but in databse I have 3 records with name "Dobre". Method `print_r()` return:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 261 [name] => Dobre [province_id] => 2
>   ) [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjjTG.png) => Array ( [id] => 1128 [name] => Dobre [province_id] => 7 ) [2]
>   => Array ( [id] => 1992 [name] => Dobre Miasto [province_id] => 14 ) )

I don't know how I can set number of number of array in this line `[0]`:

```
echo $someArray[0]["name"];
```

Comment: have you tried the json_decode() method.

Answer (score 3):

first you convert json into array. used `json_decode()`.  [for more information about json handle in PHP](https://jonsuh.com/blog/convert-loop-through-json-php-javascript-arrays-objects/)

```
// Convert JSON string to Array
  $someArray = json_decode($someJSON, true);
  print_r($someArray);
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer, but still not correct work, where there are the same place names. I edit my post when I used `json_decode()`

Answer (score 0):

**For PHP**

You can use `json_decode()`

```
$array = json_decode('[{"id":261,"name":"Dobre","province_id":2},{"id":1128,"name":"Dobre","province_id":7},{"id":1992,"name":"Dobre Miasto","province_id":14}]');

for ($i=0; $i<=count($array); $i++) {
  echo $array [$i]->name;
}
```

If you are receiving this json in your javascript code block then you need to use `JSON.parse()` .

you need to pass your json into parse method like ,

```
var obj = JSON.parse('[{"id":261,"name":"Dobre","province_id":2},{"id":1128,"name":"Dobre","province_id":7},{"id":1992,"name":"Dobre Miasto","province_id":14}]'); 

alert(obj[0]['id']) // it will return 261
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need convert Json in php

Comment: Not work in colnsole I have error: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, just I change loop to `foreach`:

```
    foreach ($villages as $key => $value) {
      echo "<a href='".$value["id"]."'>".$value["name"]."</a><br>";
    }
```

Help me this link: [Convert and Loop through JSON with PHP and JavaScript Arrays/Objects](https://jonsuh.com/blog/convert-loop-through-json-php-javascript-arrays-objects/) from [Bilal Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47904697/6678345).

Answer (score 0):

Based on you text
"But when I search name "Dobre" return only one record, but in databse I have 3 records with name "Dobre". Method print_r() return:"

Your problem is not the json related but it return only one record instead of third right?

You need to iterate through your records data.

something like this maybe

```
public function query($name) {
    $villages = Village::select('id','name', 'province_id')->where('name', 'like', '%' . $name . '%')->get();
    $returnQuery = '';

    try {
        $villages = json_decode($villages, true);
        for ($i=0; $i < count($villages); $i++) {
          $returnQuery = '<a href="">' . $villages[$i]['name'] . '</a>';
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Always good idea to catch json to prevent error if bad data is pass.
    }

    if ($returnQuery != '') {
      return $returnQuery;
    } else {
      return "Nic nie mam";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank, I've already solved this problem ;) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47905488/6678345)